# Hide set of columns in a Grid View whose datasource is a custom class

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have custom class which has 10 properties in it. I have to display only five of those as columns in a grid view.
So far I had tried this:

```
gridView1.DataSource = reservation; // This is a List of ReservationDomain (Custom Class with the properties I want to populate in the gridview)
gridView1.DataBind();
gridView1.Columns[2].Visible = false; // At this point of time the Columns count is ZERO, so an exception is thrown.
```

What's the way to do it.
I searched but every where I could find the same way of doing it or through LINQ, which internally is also doing the same thing.

Comment: please answer this question too: Its kind of similar but different in few aspects ... 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21478906/hiding-additional-attributes-in-a-list-of-objects-to-be-binded-to-a-gridview-c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvUserInfo" runat="server" >
<Columns>
<asp:BoundField DataField="Column1" HeaderText="Column1" Visible="False" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="Column2" HeaderText="Column2" />
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need `Browsable(false)` attribute

```
public class MyClass
{
    [Browsable(false)]
    public int MyProperty {get;set;}//property you don't want to show
}
```

You need to set this in your custom class's property
I think in your case you need to set this in `ReservationDomain` class

**Edit**

```
    GridView1.RowCreated -= GridView1_RowCreated;
    GridView1.RowCreated += GridView1_RowCreated;

    void GridView1_RowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Row.Cells[1].Visible = false;
    }
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Sorry didn't understand where to use it. My gridview doesn't has that property. I am using .NET 4.0... Sorry got it.. You meant the custom class right?

Comment: @UserM yes you got it

Comment: we need to include System.Attribute for this and I can't find it the references. I'll try this and let you know. Thanks for the reply. Is it similar to [DoNotMap] attribute?

Comment: If not subscribe `RowCreated` event and set e.Row.Cells[1].Visible = false;

Comment: Got an alternate way of implementing it, earlier I was auto generating the fields, now I am adding the fields through the 'Edit Columns' option of the grid view. Couldn't get the way of doing it in the code behind... Thanks Sriram for your response, I got to know couple of other things too.

Comment: @UserM yes but autogenerate helps when you want to show most of the columns except some..

Comment: I agree Sriram but in my case I had to display only half of them. It would have been better if I would have done that programatically rather than selecting every column.